# How do I make a grouped Kendo Grid collapsible by default?

Tags: jquery, kendo-ui

Here is what I have so far:

```
 $(reportTableSelector).kendoGrid({
    dataSource: dataSource,
    sortable: false,
    pageable: false,
    scrollable: false,
    columns: colModel
});

var grid = $(reportTableSelector).data("kendoGrid");
grid.collapseGroup(grid.tbody.find(">tr.k-grouping-row"));
$('tr[role*="row"]').hide();
```

If I put the last three lines of code in a `click` handler function, it will effectively collapse all the grouped rows but not when calling it after initializing the `grid`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's because during the initialization the data is still not received (you are probably using remote data) and therefore not rendered.

What you can do is invoking `collapseGroup` once the data is received and bound:

```
$(reportTableSelector).kendoGrid({
    dataSource: dataSource,
    sortable: false,
    pageable: false,
    scrollable: false,
    columns: colModel,
    dataBound: function () {
        var grid = $(reportTableSelector).data("kendoGrid");
        grid.collapseGroup(grid.tbody.find(">tr.k-grouping-row"));
        $('tr[role*="row"]').hide();
    }
});
```

Comment: nice, I thought it might have to do with autobinding the data. I'll give this a try. Thanks!

Comment: Running `$('tr[role*="row"]').hide()` will also hide the column header row. I assumed that the first row was the header and used `$('tr[role*="row"]').slice(1).hide()`

Answer (score 11):

A more idiomatic way of doing it

```
var collapseAllGroups = function (grid) {
    grid.table.find(".k-grouping-row").each(function () {
        grid.collapseGroup(this);
    });
}

//On the grid
dataBound: function (e) {
    collapseAllGroups(this);
}
```

Comment: It looks like this caused the PDF export to show the collapsed version only.  If you manually collapse all of the rows, the PDF export will still show all.

Answer (score 3):

The selected answer will cause rows to disappear when a grouping has not been applied or if the default grouping is removed.

It is better to use:

```
dataBound: function () {
    $(reportTableSelector).find('.k-icon.k-i-collapse').trigger('click');
}
```

as shown here: http://jsfiddle.net/valchev/T64Kb/

(taken from http://www.kendoui.com/forums/kendo-ui-web/grid/grid-collapse-exand-all-groups.aspx)

Note: I could not get '.k-icon.k-collapse' to work in Kendo.2013.2.716 but '.k-icon.k-i-collapse' did work.

Comment: Just like the other answer - It looks like this caused the PDF export to show the collapsed version only.  If you manually collapse all of the rows, the PDF export will still show all.

Comment: Additional info: for Kendo.2014 there is no `k-i-collapse` class - now we should use `k-minus`: `$(reportTableSelector).find('.k-icon.k-minus').trigger('click');`.

Answer (score 0):

```
dataBound: function (e) {
        var grid = this;
        $(".k-grouping-row").each(function (e) {
            grid.collapseGroup(this);
        });
    },
```

Comment: I would recommend that you add some explanatory text to your answer, or you risk having it deleted as 'low quality' (even though it may be a correct answer)!